# Twitter Block translation

Tags: blocks, i18n-l10n, social-network

I've got a TwitterBlock on my website. It works fine but all texts are in english.
Even if I change t('') function with my language (french) desired, it's still in english.

ex:ln422 twitter_block.module

```
'#title' => t('Tweets by @username', array('@username' => $config['username'])),
```

to

```
'#title' => 'Tweets par @me',
```

It still display 'Tweets by @username' in my page. 
The language input seems to be ignored to in admin/structure/block/manage/twitter_block/1 when I wrote 'fr' in it.

I hope that my problem is a minor oversight on my part. All tips are good (even the simplest).

Thanks in advance.

PS: when I try to do a `dsm($block)` in twitter_block.module or `dsm($content)` in my override block I get all my values in french.

Answer (score 0):

1. Do you have French language on you site?
2. You should not change code of contrib modules. You can override, extend it in your custom module.
3. If you have fr  language on site , back t() with EN labels, go to admin/config/regional/translate/translate try to search EN labels and translate them.

---

Another way to get translations, use module [l10n_update](https://www.drupal.org/project/l10n_update), it can get translation if they available on Localization servers.

Comment: 1. yes I have. 2. I know but it's to show how strange is my prob. 3. I translated them from your URL but nothing change.

I tried l10n_update, there are missing translations for 2 projects but not TwitterBlock... :/

Comment: ok, you translated strings, did you switch to French version of the site? clear cache?

Comment: Yes, default language is French and cache has been clear. New fact, when I reload page, I just see the sentence "Tweets par @username" as a link but nothing else, and after, my block appears and is display in english.